# Transform scale property not working in Chrome & Safari

Tags: css

```css
.tricky {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0px solid;
  background: #2373bd;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tricky_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .6s ease;
  -o-transition: all .6s ease;
  transition: all .6s ease;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tricky_image:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="tricky">
    <img class="tricky_image" src="location_images/sanfranciscoweb.png" alt="Example">
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

my desired effect is only working in Firefox and i assume IE. I am starting with a transparent image with a div wrapper around it with a blue background. When the user hovers over the image, i want it to zoom in and restore the opacity to 100% without breaking the set width and height of the div wrapper. This works perfectly in Firefox, but when i run the animation in Chrome the image exceeds the width of the blue div wrapper behind it. Here is my code and any help would be appreciated & JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yaLupdzo/1/:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .tricky {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 0px solid;
      background: #2373bd;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .tricky_image {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
      -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
      -ms-transition: all .6s ease;
      -o-transition: all .6s ease;
      transition: all .6s ease;
      opacity: 0.7;
      border-radius: 50%;
      filter: alpha(opacity=70);
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .tricky_image:hover {
      opacity: 1;
      filter: alpha(opacity=100);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="tricky">
    <img class="tricky_image" src="location_images/sanfranciscoweb.png" alt="Example">
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please create a Fiddle (jsfiddle.net) to visualize your problem.

Comment: Did my answer below help at all?

Comment: For others who find this I was using `scale(45%)` which worked in FF but not in Chrome.  Switching to `scale(0.45)` fixed it.

Answer (score 12):

This is a known issue as filed here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157218

In Webkit, with hardware acceleration, animated layers get promoted to a different rendering surface during animation, and then demoted once the animation is complete.

Turns out there is a simple solution. Have the container element 'promoted' to the same rendering layer as the hardware accelerated child by adding a lightweight animation to it:

```
.tricky {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    background: #2373bd;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.0);
}

.tricky_image {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.tricky:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.0);
}

.tricky:hover .tricky_image {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
 }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/yaLupdzo/3/

Note that I've also added a simple animation to the parent container's default state, so that the same issue doesn't happen when hovering out.

Comment: If anyone is willing to help me again it would be much appreciated. I am having another problem with this code. While this solution works in chrome, it still has the same effect in Safari and Firefox. I applied the necessary webkit properties to the code but it still isn't working in those browsers.

Comment: Please post an example.

Comment: Hi @AlexandreBourlier could you post a JSFiddle as well? I'd be happy to help out but you'd need to provide more info.

Answer (score 6):

```
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
```

You can repeat your code like that for browser compatibility..