# css: translate value is not working

Tags: html, css

the translate value in the `.arrow` does not seem to have any effect here. can somebody explain me why

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container{
    height:500px;
    width:600px;
}
.header{ height:40px; }
.step{width:194px;float:left; border:1px solid black; height:40px;}

.arrow{display:inline-block;width:25px; height:25px; border-left:1px solid 
 black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;-webkit-transform:translateY(20px); 
 transform:rotate(-135deg);  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='header'>
      <div class='step'> step 1 <div class='arrow'> </div></div>
      <div class='step'> step 2 <div class='arrow'> </div></div>
      <div class='step'> step 3 <div class='arrow'> </div></div>
    <div class='body'> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform scale property not working in Chrome & Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372315/transform-scale-property-not-working-in-chrome-safari)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add both *values* to the same `transform` property like `transform: translateY(20px) rotate(-135deg)`, otherwise only the last one will be taken into account, because of the *CSS cascading rule*:

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
}

.step {
  width: 194px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 40px;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  transform: translateY(20px) rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
    <div class='step'> step 1 <div class='arrow'> </div></div>
    <div class='step'> step 2 <div class='arrow'> </div></div>
    <div class='step'> step 3 <div class='arrow'> </div></div>
  <div class='body'></div>
</div>
```