# CSS transform works on Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transforms

I am trying a thing in CSS where the background of a text is an image and when we hover over the text, it scales to a very large number that the the image used as the font color shows up completely. It works perfectly on Mozilla Firefox, but the transform property of CSS seems to be broken on Chrome and the text just vanishes on hover on Chrome.

```css
/* font */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@900&display=swap');

/* reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

body,
html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #999;
}


/* styling */

.container {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/900/800");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .image-text {
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 2s linear;
}

.container .image-text:hover {
  transform: scale(200);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-text">
    Hover
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Scale is not supported: https://caniuse.com/?search=scale

Comment: Is there any workaround for Chrome?

Comment: try this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372315/transform-scale-property-not-working-in-chrome-safari/40520826

Comment: @PeterS while it is true that scale as such is not supported in Chrome, I believe transform: scale(..) is and that seems to be what is being used here (or was that after an edit?)

Comment: PeterS is looking at the wrong property. It is https://caniuse.com/transforms2d which shows the support for `transform: scale(x, y)`, see also [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that any sort of transform creates a new stacking context so the clip text isn't effective. [That is one of the things that the CSS property scale does for you - takes it away from being a transform - but it isn't supported by Chrome/Edge].

If we do away with a transform of scale and instead increase the font-size and transition on that you get what I think is the effect you want:

```css
/* font */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@900&display=swap');

/* reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

body,
html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #999;
}


/* styling */

.container {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/900/800");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .image-text {
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  transition: font-size 2s linear;
}

.container .image-text:hover {
  font-size: 200em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-text">
    Hover
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work fine everywhere, but I was thinking of scaling because I might have a case where the `container` is a complex card with images and texts and I insert a text at the exact center of it. So when we hover on the card, the card along with all of its content scales up keeping the central text as the point of scale.

Comment: Understood, changing just font size is rather a special, limited case. It will be good if Chrome etc implement the separate scale property.

Comment: Yes. Another thing I noticed about font-size, after a point it stops growing. I went up to a font-size of one million em (no sane person would do that) and still some part of the image left off.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Chrome doesn't render it correctly. It does, when you use `zoom`, you just lose the transition then...

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@900&display=swap');


.container {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/900/800");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .image-text {
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 2s linear;
}

.container .image-text:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(200);
  zoom: 200;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-text">
    Hover
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `zoom` property not animatable in CSS? I referred [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) which had `zoom` in it.

Comment: @deekeh Hmmm, interesting. I assumed it from being non-standard, and the Chrome behaviour. I don't have access to Microsoft browsers, where I think zoom comes from.

Comment: I tried `transition: zoom 1s;` and it did not work. Seems broken.